# Funnelweb migration causing errors because of invalid folder name

Tags: plone-funnelweb

I have a folder named "view" and this seems to be causing some errors while migration. Can I rename it on the fly? Is there an example for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the name under invalid_ids under the urltidy step in your pipeline.cfg.

```
[urltidy]
invalid_ids = view
```

"layout" is another that seems to cause problems.